# Load, show and convert multiple images

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm starting to write my first program in C++ with OpenCV and I would like to represent a set of images (stored in my project and libelled "brain_mri_001.jpg -> brain_mri_015.jpg) as vectors of length LxL where L is the number of pixels in the x(y) direction. 
Here is my code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        //load images
        for(int i=1; i<=25; i++)
            {
                char filename[50];
                sprintf( filename, "brain_mri_%d.jpg", i ); 
                IplImage *img=cvLoadImage( filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
                if (!img)   
                    {
                        printf("Error: Image not found.\n");
                        return 2; //error : not found image
                    }

                cvNamedWindow("Projet Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// create a window
                IplImage *img2=cvCloneImage(img); //clone img
                cvShowImage("Projet Image", img2); // display the image in a window

                cvWaitKey(0); //attendre touche
                cvDestroyWindow("Projet Image"); // destroy the window
                cvReleaseImage(&img); // memory

                return 0; //finish with success

                //convert IplImage -> Matrix 
                int height = img->height;  
                int width = img->width; 
                CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(height,width,CV_32FC3);

                //convert Matrix -> Vector 
                //CvMat row_header, *row;
                //row = cvReshape(mat, &row_header, 0, 1);
                CvMat vector_header;
                cvReshape(img, &vector_header, 0, 1);

                //check the height and width of vector_header
                if(vector_header.height != 1)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "vector_header's height is %d\n", vector_header.height);
                    }
                if(vector_header.width != width*height)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "vector_header's width is %d\n", vector_header.width);
                    }
            }
    }
```

I should have made a mistake but I don't know where :(
I would be grateful if anyone can answer me !
P.S. Excuse my bad English...

Comment: I know that it might sound scary and all, but why not use [C++ API](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/refman.html)? Most of avaliable tutorials are based on C API, but it uses a lot of pointers and there is lots of places where You can make hard to detect mistakes. If You write in C++, go full C++ :)

Comment: @Link +1 There is hardly any reason to use the C interface in a C++ program, but well, neither is there any to use `cstdio` over `iostream`.

Comment: @Ivoa70 What exactly is the error?  I see, for example, that you haven't `cvReleaseImage`d your images, but I don't know if that's causing your error.    @Link, I think you answered your own question: most of the tutorials are based on the C API, which is already daunting enough for new users.  Could you point out a really good tutorial that uses the C++ API?

Comment: Thanks Link and Christian for your suggestions ! But I must use OpenCV in my project :( I don't have the choice...

Comment: @dantswain, You've right ! I added cvReleaseImage to my code 
But I'm not sure my conversion works, I mean if all my images (matrix) are converted into vectors or not.

Comment: @dantswain Well, I've started to use OpenCV nearly a year ago, and I just read c tutorials and used c++ api. It's not that hard to look up what functions in c++ replace those in c. And, there are appearing some tutorials on (site with 3.2 documentation)[http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html].

Comment: @Ivoa70 C++ API is still OpenCV, but a bit easier to read :) Which version do You use?

Comment: @Link Thanks for the link :) I've no opposition to using the C++ API, but I think OP would like to solve their problem before trying to grok a new API.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is a) `cvReleaseImage` your images when you're done with them, and 2) your reshape code should be something like this

```
CvMat vector_header;
cvReshape(img2, &vector_header, 0, 1); /* same # of channels, 1 row */
```

Note that `cvReshape` doesn't copy the data, so `vector_header` doesn't need to be allocated with `cvCreateMat`.  I'm not sure how to test this, except maybe to try loading in a very small image and plotting its values to stdout.  As a sanity check, you could check the `height` and `width` of vector_header, something like

```
if(vector_header.height != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "vector_header's height is %d\n", vector_header.height);
}
if(vector_header.width != width*height)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "vector_header's width is %d\n", vector_header.width);
}
```

I might have that backwards in terms of height and width.  I'm also not 100% sure how the reshape will go, i.e. if your image is [1 2; 3 4], will the resulting vector be [1 2 3 4] or [1 3 2 4]?  If you're doing something like PCA (e.g., the eigenfaces algorithm), then it might not matter as long as it's consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually, this is the first part of a program using PCA to classify brain MRI images so I think it will be OK. My question is how can I, please, be sure that they (the images) are all loaded and converted into matrix and then into vectors ?
I updated my code in the first message I posted.